# django custom templatetag not getting request in context

Tags: django, django-templates

I am using django 1.4 and trying to convert the code described at the end of [this article](http://dashdrum.com/blog/2010/03/full-url-in-django/) into a customtag. This means I need access to the is_secure and site_name values from the request. Here is my CONTEXT_PROCESSORS in settings.py:

```
CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
)
```

Here is my template tag code:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def full_static_url(context, url):
    request = context['request']
    scheme = 'http'
    if request.is_secure:
        scheme += 's'
    return scheme + '://' + request.site_name + context['STATIC_URL'] + url
```

In my view code I am using the new render shortcut like so:

```
return render(request, 'myapp/mytemplate.html', {'foo':bar})
```

And I am calling it like this in the template:

```
{% full_static_url "images/logo.gif" %}
```

The problem is, when it gets to the line **request = context['request']** it throws a KeyError because 'request' is not in context.

What am I doing wrong here?

Full traceback is:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Projects\blah\blah\myapp\views\myview.py" in manifestcosts
  44.     return render(request, 'myapp/mytemplate.html', {'foo':bar})
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts\__init__.py" in render
  44.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs),
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  176.         return t.render(context_instance)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  140.             return self._render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  185.                         nodelist.append(node.render(context))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  1107.                     return func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
File "C:\Projects\blah\blah\myapp\templatetags\mytags.py" in full_static_url
  25.     request = context['request']        #TODO this fails with an KeyError, don't know why
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\context.py" in __getitem__
  54.         raise KeyError(key)

Exception Type: KeyError at /myapp/myurl/110505081136179000/
Exception Value: 'request'
```

Comment: Try this. http://squeeville.com/2009/01/27/django-templatetag-requestcontext-and-inclusion_tag/

Comment: @CppLearner I tried it but, as I suspected, same issue. KeyError when it tries to get the request out of the context map.

Comment: Just as sanity check, do you have really CONTEXT_PROCESSORS, or the better variant TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS in your settings.py ?

Comment: Sorry, I had to jump on other tasks and just now getting back to this issue.  @loomi I am really using CONTEXT_PROCESSORS, I was not aware of TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS. I will give that a try though and let you know.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm having exactly the same problem right now. Everything looks right in my code, but the request object is just not being passed.

Comment: I did not. I needed it done so I'm sad to say I just repeated the code where it was needed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The right way to fix this issue is to add `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS += ("django.core.context_processors.request",)` on your settings.py file.

Ensure to import `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` first with `from django.conf.global_settings import TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` or it will not work.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing after estecb's comment on Pheonix's answer above. You are the first to actually write this up as an answer.  Thanks!

Comment: In more recent versions of Django, TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS is deprecated and has been replaced with TEMPLATES['OPTIONS']['context_processors']. Do you what to import instead in that circumstance?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the problem is you are rendering your template using regular context, that is something like this:

```
return render_to_response("myapp/template.html", {"some_var": a_value})
```

Remember that context processors are only applied to `RequestContext` instances. That means you have to either explicitly create a `RequestContext` in your `render_to_response` call:

```
return render_to_response("myapp/template.html", {"some_var": a_value},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

or even better, use the new `render` shortcut:

```
return render(request, "myapp/template.html", {"some_var": a_value})
```

Comment: Actually, I am using the render shortcut. I should have mentioned that in my description. I will add it now.

Comment: Just in case, I tried the render_to_response approach (with the RequestContext)  same issue.

Comment: Well, in that case the code looks right, could you paste the exact traceback you are getting?

Comment: added the stack trace to the question above

Comment: Okay, two things pop to my mind: 1) try creating a `RequestContext` instance inside your view and logging (printing or whatever) its `dicts` attribute to see if it contains the `request` item. 2) try logging `context.dicts` from inside your template tag to check it gets the right context instance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing

```
return render(request, 'myapp/mytemplate.html', {'foo':bar})
```

to

```
return render( RequestContext(request), 'myapp/mytemplate.html', {'foo':bar})
```

I hope this helps someone else, I wasted about 8 hours :p

Comment: the second code is wrong, render already does that. You are probably missing `django.core.context_processors.request` in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`.

Comment: This works but IMHO it is not the best solution. I think lithiium's solution of adding to the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen in a template.Node object in the render(). It turned out that sometimes the context had 'request' in it, other times it didn't.

Like someone else suggested, `RequestContext(request)` is the key. My guess is that sometimes the context is called without the request being initialized like that.

I changed my function from

```
 def render(self, context):
      request = context['request']  # Failing here
```

to

```
 def render(self, context):
      request = RequestContext(context)['request']['request']
```

and it all came right.

This will force a request object in case the context object wasn't initialized properly. For some reason I had to add ['request'] twice, but it seems to work fine

---

**EDIT**: I spoke too soon, seems a blank context can't be fixed. Instead you could try a workaround:

```
request = context.get('request')
if request is None:
    return ''
```

My page still seems to work fine, so I'm not exactly sure where these bad contexts are coming from.