# KeyError at - request - django templatetag

Tags: django, django-templates

Here is my code in template tag

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True, name=CAR_TEMPLATE_TAG_NAME)
def g_c(context,session_key=None,c_class=Car):
    request = context['request']  
    return c_class(request, session_key=session_key)
```

In the template it is used as `{% g_c as car %}` and the issue is keyerror 'request' at `request = context['request']`

Here is my template context,

```
'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
               # 'django.core .context_processors.request,
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
```

Here is the try out,

[image]

Here is the new line added in templatetag

```
from django.conf import TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS
```

In setting added

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = 'django.template.context_processors.request'
```

Comment: Please post a gist of your context too from the views

Comment: @Vishal.R please check my context

Comment: Sorry!! If I understood your question, {% g_c as car %} this is how I render in the template

Comment: Did you try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10288868/django-custom-templatetag-not-getting-request-in-context. Seems similar.

Comment: @Vishal.R please check my updated question with the workaround

Comment: That answer is from an extremely old version of Django and is no longer valid. But please can you show the view that is rendering the template this tag is on?

Comment: This is a templatetag, and I guess there is no view for this and we can utilize it directly in the template.. Am I right @DanielRoseman

Comment: Yes but if it's relying on the template context, then you need to have the request in that context. And since that is added by the context processor, the view that is rendering the template needs to be using a RequestContext (eg via the `render` shortcut). So please show the view.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Possible to show as an example, this is added in header which comes in every page, so this is not available only on specific view

Comment: @Prabhakaran8737 Error can not be reproduced with code pieces you provided and latest version of django. There must be something else besides this code. Please provide django version information and all imports you are doing in template tags file and are you upgrading from an older version of django?

Comment: @Prabhakaran8737 what django version are you using ??

Answer (score 0):

You must import settings first:

```
from django.conf.settings import TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS
```

Answer (score 0):

The default settings includes the request template context processor which adds the request to be used in the template.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/templates/#configuration
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

To access the context

```
DEFAULT_C_CLASS = Car

@register.simple_tag(name=CAR_TEMPLATE_TAG_NAME, takes_context=True)
def g_c(context, session_key=None, c_class=None):
    request = context['request']
    c_class = c_class or DEFAULT_C_CLASS
    session_key = session_key or request.session.session_key

    # Note this class __init__ should return a fragment.
    return c_class(request, session_key=session_key)
```

`base.html`

```
{% load my_custom_tag %} 

{% g_c as car %}
```

You could also pass the request object directly in the template

```
@register.simple_tag(name='g_c')
def g_c(request, session_key=None, c_class=None):
    c_class = c_class or DEFAULT_C_CLASS
    session_key = session_key or request.session.session_key

    # Note this class __init__ should return a fragment.
    return c_class(request, session_key=session_key)
```

`base.html`

```
 {% load my_custom_tag %} 

 {% g_c request as car %}
```